# Get error when executing Update-Database in Code First EF

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Im using Entity Framework and Code First. Connections to db works fine until i want to create a new Migration. Keep getting this error:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
```

Normal read and write to the tables works fine.

I can also execute a rollback with line

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration xxx
```

Only the forward way I gives me trouble

Comment: Are you able to check the logs of the database server you're accessing? Something _should_ be written there.

Comment: Try these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714569/cannot-get-rid-of-physical-connection-is-not-usable-exception