# SqlException: Error 19

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I keep running into this error message while debugging a .Net application:

"A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)"
It is not branch-specific, and I encounter it whether I am pointing to the development database or production database.  My IIS settings, network settings are identical to the other developers.  We have tried replacing the network card, turned off wifi on my computer, and validated that I do not have any packet loss or unusual latency.

I encounter this while using my local sites hosted with IIS.  I can interact with the website for five to ten minutes without encountering the error, or I can interact with it for one minute and it pops up.  After the error shows, it then shows almost every time I try to interact with the site.

I have tried disabling/reenabling IIS, upgrading to Windows 10, updating SSMS

This is unique because the other developers are not experiencing this issue even with the same development branch.  I have tried recycling the app pool and it does nothing.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: The error means SQL Server closed the connection while .NET's connection pool thinks the associated connection is still usable. make sure to close, dispose, and whatever not your connections.

Comment: Closing my reader would explain the error if the other developers were getting the error, but they are not, even when using the same exact development branch.

Comment: Does https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7800 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714569/cannot-get-rid-of-physical-connection-is-not-usable-exception or https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/ help?

Comment: Have any of your team tried on your PC / laptop & have you tried a a PC / laptop that is known to work for someone else?

Comment: @mjwills this error does not show for other developers, using the exact same dev branch.  I am thinking this is an IIS or local configuration issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server)

Comment: @PhilipWeiser The thing I would caution you against is jumping to a conclusion too early.