# Getting a SQL Server exception only in one environment "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

We have two servers and connected with each other via load balancer. We have our database in different server. We are following same architecture on Dev and QA environment as well. Currently we are facing an issue only in our Production environment where we can see a SQL Server related exception on our log.

We are using ASP.NET MVC 5, SQL Server 2017.

The exception is as follows:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
>   An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred and was caught.
>
> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred and was caught.
>
> Type : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> Message : A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable) Source : .Net SqlClient Data Provider Help link :
>
> Errors :
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection ClientConnectionId :
>   8bc28cc4-cdd0-4641-ada1-af76e497c86e Class : 20 LineNumber : 0 Number
>   : -1 Procedure :   State : 0 ErrorCode :
>   -2146232060 Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal TargetSite : Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean,
>   System.Action`1[System.Action]) HResult : -2146232060 Stack Trace :
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, UInt32 error)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[]
>   buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadInt64(Int64& value) 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValueInternal(SqlBuffer
>   value, Byte tdsType, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value,
>   SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
>   SqlCommandColumnEncryptionSetting columnEncryptionOverride, String
>   columnName)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i,
>   Boolean readHeaderOnly)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean
>   setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt64(Int32 i)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   DTNA.UTP.DataAccessLayer.Repositories.TechPointRepository.GetTechPointDetails(Int32
>   userType, List`1 facilities, List`1 departments, Int64 userFacility,
>   DashBoardViewList selecteddashboard)

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEmID.jpg)

We have not set any explicit value for connectionPool, and using default that is 100. We have around 10000 users currently accessing our application.
Could anyone help me to understand why this issue is happening?

Comment: Is this error intermittent, or occurred every time trying to establish connection into database? Have you read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714569/cannot-get-rid-of-physical-connection-is-not-usable-exception) already?

Comment: This is a intermittent issue. Yes, I read it. But no luck

Comment: @user1996300 Do you solve the issue?