# sql exception "physical connection is not usable" on a specific column in specific table

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6, .net-4.6

I have a winforms desktop app. It works on the server computer, where the db is, but on another computer, with win 8.1, it throws the error only when selecting 2 specific columns from 2 tables. First column is image type, the other is nchar(250) type. I'm using EF6, but even if I write raw sql, I get the same exception. The exception does not occur on client machines running win 10.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The connection string is `Data Source=172.16.100.100;Initial Catalog=ss;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

As I said every code, that selects the mentioned columns from the db triggers it. Eg:
`context.ProblematicTable.ToList()` ; `context.ProblematicTable.Select(x=>x.ProblemColumn)` ;
`context.ExecuteStoreQuery<ProblematicTable>("select ProblematicColumn from ProblematicTable")`

Selecting other columns does not raise errors. Eg:
`context.ProblematicTable.Select(x=>x.AnyOtherColumn)`

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714569/cannot-get-rid-of-physical-connection-is-not-usable-exception

Comment: It doesn't happen randomly, but every time one of the two columns is selected from the db

Comment: Okay - their issue was due to how the connection string refenced the database. I wondered whether there was a similar issue here. Please post up the code that triggers this error along with table definition and your connection string - NOTE replace sensitive information such as username and passwords or keys, but leave the syntax and punctuation the same.

Comment: As for the table definition, I already stated the problematic columns' data types, what else would you need to know? These tables and the app have been working for a long time, with multiple computers in the same domain, accessing the server db, and selecting these tables never raised errors. That's why I think it has something to do with the windows version, because that's the only difference that I can find, and also maybe the data types of these columns, the image column can be quite big(still we had no problems with it before)